# Google Sheets SUMIF criteria - How to refer to the cell being evaluated?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

[image: Sum for the month]

Refer sheet above. In column E, I need the sum of 'StockCount' for the month of July-18. The formula should look at all dates in column B (EventDate) and sum the stock count only if the event is in the same month as in column A.

I'm trying SumIf in different ways but perhaps this isn't the right function to use. Note that I don't want to add an extra column to the sheet.

Basically, I'd like something like if 'Cell being evaluated'-Cell A < 31 and >0, THEN add a stock count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column A contains a date which is the first day of each month, you can use this filled down from cell E3:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A3<>"",sumif(date(year(B$3:B),month(B$3:B),1),A3,C$3:C),""))
```

(it has to be entered as an array formula to convert the whole of column B to dates).

or better

```
=if(A3<>"",sumifs(C$3:C,B$3:B, ">="&A3,B$3:B,"<="&eomonth(A3,0)),"")
```

But you can also use this self-expanding array formula in E3:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A3:A<>"",sumif(date(year(B3:B),month(B3:B),1),A3:A,C3:C),""))
```

[image]

Comment: This and the above answer worked for me (both being similar of course) but I marked this as I found it more useful because of the options being offered. I still don't understand arrayformulas completely though.  How is it that =ArrayFormula(if(A3:A<>"",sumif(date(year(B3:B),month(B3:B),1),A3:A,C3:C),"")) makes the formula self expanding?   Is it because we expressed the criterion as a **range**? I understand that it's due to the fact that we added A3:A but how does it know that it should use the 'criterion' from each subsequent cell but still use the entire 'range' for testing each criterion?

Comment: In SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range]), the range and [sum_range] are always ranges. With a single criterion, the SUMIF works it way down checking each cell in the range against the criterion and adding the sum_range if it matches, delivering a single result (although the range can also be an array, it still works the same way). When the criterion is an array, it performs the previous 'inner loop' to deliver a single result for the first array element, but there is now an 'outer loop', so it repeats the process for the second element in the criterion array etc. returning multiple results.

Answer (score 1):

paste this in **E3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A<>"", SUMIF(DATE(YEAR(B3:B), MONTH(B3:B), 1), 
 DATE(20&RIGHT(A3:A, 2), TEXT(A3:A, "MM"), 1), C3:C), ))
```

or this in **E2** cell:

```
={"sum per A column"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A<>"", SUMIF(DATE(YEAR(B3:B), MONTH(B3:B), 1), 
 DATE(20&RIGHT(A3:A, 2), TEXT(A3:A, "MM"), 1), C3:C), ))}
```

[image: 0]